# BC30451: 'NewsBody' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net

Try as i might i cant get past this error. I'm not an ASP.Net developer but due to reasons outside my control have to develop 2-3 pages in ASP.

I'm using Dreamweaver and have the asp.net set to compile at first load.

**.aspx File**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"  Src="Scripts/CurrentNews.aspx.vb" Inherits="NewsFunctionality" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/NewsLayoutOne.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="OuterDiv" runat="server">
        <img id="NewsImage" src="Images/DefaultNews1.png" >
        <div id="NewsBody" runat="server">Original Text</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**.aspv.vb file**

```
' VB Document
public partial Class NewsFunctionality
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    'On load event for the page linked to this class file
   protected sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       NewsBody.InnerHTML = "<p>Dynamic Text Generated.</p>"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Open up the `.designer.vb` file. Is there a declaration for `NewBody` in it?

Comment: I'm stuck building this in Dreamweaver so there's no auto generated .designer.vb file.

What method should i be using to generate the .designer.vb file for a site that is **not** precompiled

Answer (score 0):

Check that **'NewsBody'** have been declared within  the **designer.vb** file.

It could look something like this since you are using a div:

```
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl NewsBody;
```

Comment: How would i create or generate this designer.vb file without visual Studios?

Or rather where should i be looking in order to learn these details / What are the key terms my searches should contain?